# Formulario django sin usar form de django

Tags: django

Tengo un formulario elaborado sin usar los form de django(Fue uno de los requisitos que me exigieron, no usar los form de django). 
Este formulario lo uso para crear y para editar.
El formulario crea y edita perfectamente, pero encuentro un error(lo llamo asi) ya que en la url cuando edita me sigue cargando el id del cliente. como hago para limpiar esa URL

este es la view

```
def clientes_editar(request, id_cliente):
    cliente = Cliente.objects.get(id = id_cliente)
    if request.method == 'GET': #para q cargue los datos en el template
        datos={'nombre':cliente.nombre,'numero_documento':cliente.documento,\
            'email':cliente.email,'ciudad':cliente.ciudad}
        return render(request,'estructuracion/cliente_crear.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':#para guardar los datos una vez modificados
            cliente.nombre = request.POST['nombre']
            cliente.documento = request.POST['numero_documento']
            cliente.email = request.POST['email']
            cliente.ciudad = Ciudad.objects.get(pk = request.POST['ciudad'])
            cliente.save()

    return render(request,'estructuracion/cliente_consultar.html')
```

URL http://localhost:8000/estructuracion/clienteseditar/1/

URL despues de editar http://localhost:8000/estructuracion/clienteseditar/1/

Quisiera que la url despues de quedar quedara asi http://localhost:8000/estructuracion/clientesConsultar

url.py

```
url(r'^clientes$', clientes_create, name='clientes'),
url(r'^clienteseditar/(?P<id_cliente>\d+)/$', clientes_editar, name='clientes_editar'),
url(r'^clientesConsultar$', clientes_consultar,name='clientes_consultar'),
```

Comment: ¿Puedes publicar tu archivo `urls.py`, la parte donde defines como llegar a `clientesConsultar`?

Comment: Listo añadi el archivo de urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que veo es que simplemente estas cambiando el template, mas no estas redireccionando a otra vista, esto es básicamente lo que debes hacer, una vez creas tu cliente con los datos del "formulario", debes enviarlo a otra vista que apunte a otra url, de lo contrario, como estas haciendo, cargara otro template, pero con la misma url, un ejemplo seria...

```
...
cliente.save()
return redirect('consultar_cliente')  # en caso que tenga nombre la url
return HttpResponseRedirect('/estructuracion/clientesConsultar')  # en el caso contrario
...
```

y esa url debe apuntar a otra vista, que esa vista a su vez debe retornar el template que quieres mostrar en este caso supongo que seria `return render(request,'estructuracion/cliente_consultar.html')` y listo, asi manejas cada logica de cada pagina de manera independiente y ordenada, Espero haberte ayudado, cualquier duda comenta

Comment: Archivo url.py

    url(r'^clientes$', clientes_create, name='clientes'),
    url(r'^clienteseditar/(?P<id_cliente>\d+)/$', clientes_editar, name='clientes_editar'),
    url(r'^clientesConsultar$', clientes_consultar,name='clientes_consultar'),

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de tu vista, así como las estas trabajando yo las trabajaba así:

```
def EditarMovimiento(request,id):
    editar_mov = None
    error = None
    try:
        editar_mov = Movimiento.objects.get(id = id)
        if request.method == 'GET':
            editar_mov = MovimientoForm(instance = editar_mov)
        else:
            editar_mov = MovimientoForm(request.POST, instance = editar_mov)
            if editar_mov.is_valid():
                editar_mov.save()
            return redirect('listar-movimiento')
    except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
        error = e
    return render(request,'control/movimiento/nuevomovimiento.html', {'editar_mov': editar_mov,'error':error})
```

Le indico que si es metodo GET llenara mi formulario de lo contrario utilizara el POST y guardara y me dirige a mi listado de mis registros.

Te recomiendo que trabajes con Json q es muchos mas fácil lee sobre RestFrameWork y aplicarlo a tu proyecto [RestFrameWork](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)